# Update exist table with diffrent values, PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

How could I update row of many if the values changed?
I export the data from XML file which contain more than 130 rows and the same number on my MYSQL database, I want to compare it and insert if there's a new row and update the changed row.

Note: Inserting new rows working fine, but updating doesn't work!

```html
$query = "SELECT positionid FROM vacant WHERE positionid = '".$position."' and ptitle = '".$ptitle."' and location = '".$location."' and vacantd = '".$vdate."' and candidate = '".$resultcandidate."' and cv = '".$cvtorsaf."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existName = $recResult["positionid"];

if($existName=="") {
     $insertTable= mysql_query("insert into vacant (positionid, ptitle, location, vacantd, candidate, cv) values('".$position."', '".$ptitle."', '".$location."', '".$vdate."', '".$resultcandidate."', '".$cvtorsaf."');");
} else {
     $insertTable= mysql_query("UPDATE vacant SET ptitle = '".$ptitle."', location = '".$location."', vacantd = '".$vdate."', candidate = '".$resultcandidate."', cv = '".$cvtorsaf."' WHERE positionid = '".$position."'");
}
```

Comment: Just do an UPDATE like you normally do. Having a lot of values change doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Right you just have to update because it automatically affect changed rows and now existing rows .

Comment: Thnx for replying, actually it's not work: $insertTable= mysql_query("UPDATE vacant SET ptitle = '".$ptitle."', location = '".$location."', vacantd = '".$vdate."', candidate = '".$resultcandidate."', cv = '".$cvtorsaf."' WHERE positionid = '".$position."'");

Comment: Can you show me your error which you are facing .

Comment: No error, but it's not affect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Your `code` looking right still if you have `error` in updating field

then just try to `print` your `error`. use `mysql_error();`

```
$insertTable= mysql_query("UPDATE vacant SET ptitle = '".$ptitle."', location = '".$location."', vacantd = '".$vdate."', candidate = '".$resultcandidate."', cv = '".$cvtorsaf."' WHERE positionid = '".$position."'") or print_r(mysql_error());die;
```

Comment: When I replace it by mysql_query("DELETE FROM vacant WHERE positionid = '" . $position . "'")  it's just affect on the first row!